# node-postgres not executing client.query()?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I have a module `database.js` for running PostgreSQL queries in Node.JS as follows:

```
const {Client}=require('pg');

const pgclient=new Client({
    connectionString:process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl:true
});

pgclient.connect();

module.exports={

    getUser:function(phonenumber){
        queryStr='SELECT * FROM users where phonenumber=\''+phonenumber+'\';';
        console.log(queryStr);
        pgclient.query(queryStr, (err, res) => {
            console.log("rows length "+res.rows.length);
            if (err) throw err;
            if (res.rows.length==0){
                return null;
            }
            else{
                return res.rows[0];
            }           
        });
    }
}
```

When I call it, using e.g.

```
var db=require('./database');
userObj=db.getUser('+19991112222');
if (userObj==null){
    console.log("user not found");
}
else{
    console.log(userObj["phonenumber"]);
}
```

Then I get the following console logging:

```
SELECT * FROM users where phonenumber='+19991112222';
user not found
```

Because the `rows length` line does not appear in the console log, I'm thinking that the `pgclient.query()` call is either not being made, or it's immediately failing silently and returning `null` before any lines in the `(err, res) => {}` function are executed.  How can I get the query to actually run?

EDIT: I think what's happening is that when `getUser` is called, `pgclient.connect()` hasn't made its database connection yet, and so `pgclient.query()` is failing silently.  When I moved all the connection code and `getUser` into the same file that has my test procedure, it ran successfully.  So what I need to do is figure out how to have the connection established in the module by the time the exported functions are available to the test procedure.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign the result of an asynchronous function to a variable like you did in the following line:

```
userObj=db.getUser('+19991112222');
```

You have to assign it in the callback.

So, it can be done like this:

```
module.exports={

    // I am passing a callback function which takes error as first argument and data as second
    getUser:function(phonenumber, callback){
        queryStr='SELECT * FROM users where phonenumber=\''+phonenumber+'\';';
        console.log(queryStr);
        pgclient.query(queryStr, (err, res) => {
            console.log("rows length "+res.rows.length);
            if (err) return callback(err);
            if (res.rows.length==0){
                return callback(null, null);
            }
            else{
                return callback(null, res.rows[0]);
            }           
        });
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var db=require('./database');
// Here I'm passing the function which is the callback and I handle the error and user in this function.
db.getUser('+19991112222', function(err, user) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (user==null){
        console.log("user not found");
    }
    else {
        console.log(userObj["phonenumber"]);
    }
});
```

You can use promises also which does the same thing but has more functionality.

Comment: Have you tested this?  I just tested it and the only console output is the `SELECT` statement from `console.log(queryStr);`.  Because I'm still not getting the `rows length` output, I'm wondering if maybe `pgclient.query()` isn't getting called?

Comment: Please see my edit; I believe the problem has to do with `getUser()` being called before `pgclient.connect()` establishes the database connection.

Comment: You have to modify the code. I showed you the way. You have to assign and return the data you need.